# On free lattices

Tags: ct.category-theory, lattice-theory

Free distributive lattices on a finite set exist and are finite, while free modular lattices on a finite set exist but are not finite when the set has at least 4 elements.

> **Question**: Is there a class (presumably, a variety in the sense of universal algebra) $C$ of lattices larger than the class of distributive lattices such that free $C$-lattices on a finite set exist (for all finite sets) and are finite?

If yes, is there a "largest" such class $C$?

Comment: Comment: free modular lattices on $> 3$ elements are infinite.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks, I added that.

Comment: An interesting class of lattices a bit bigger than distributive lattices, and different than modular, would be semidistributive lattices. But I don't know enough about universal algebra to say whether those qualify as a variety, so that it makes sense to talk about free objects.

Comment: Ah, pg. 82 of https://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/Jipsen%20Rose%201992%20Varieties%20of%20Lattices.pdf: "The fourth statement shows that semidistributivity cannot be characterized by a set of identities, and so the class of all semidistributive lattices does not form a variety. "

Comment: An outsider's question:  is it common to cay "classs" instead of "variety" in universal algebra?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: also an outsider; but: strictly speaking, I don't think it is *required* that the class of objects be a variety for free objects to exist. Just that certainly being a variety guarantees the existence of free objects.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests free objects might exist in more general contexts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object.

Comment: Here is what you need: http://math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os8uh.pdf      Look up theorem 8.1 . Then use it to create a "mini-lattice" which is not distributive and close with respect to HSP

Comment: PS to address Andrej's question and Sam's comment: even if one looked at a class which is not a variety, by closing with respect to HSP operations you could extend it to a variety. So I think we can safely assume that the OP uses variety in the question

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci: Those are interesting notes, but  can you say explicitly what the conclusion is, i.e., what's the answer to Mare's question?

Comment: answer: right now I have just eaten penne with heavy sour cream and pesto, I could not even recite the multiplication table up to 9 :). Mine is simply a comment, maybe tomorrow, if nobody else has written an answer, I can try. But here is what I can tell you now: I would use theorem 8.1 and a judiciously chosen little lattice to generate a variety of lattices which includes distributives but not modular. As for the second part,

Comment: namely whether there is a maximal variety with the finite property, I would perhaps consider ascending list of mini-lattices and their corresponding varieties, and take, as it were, the sup. Is this a strategy? I would not bet my house on that, but perhaps worth trying....

Comment: Ah, I see, distributive lattices are HSP(2), and as explained towards the end of http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~jb/math618/os9uh.pdf, this variety is covered by both HSP($N_5$) and HSP($M_3$), and by the theorem 8.1 you linked to since these are generated by a single lattice they will have finite free objects.

Comment: Right! Theorem 8.1 and subsequent consequences give you control on the generated variety.  How about this my newly found MO friend: you write the full answer. If you do, I tell you my secret recipe to make penne al pesto + sour cream

Comment: What about the variety generated by modular lattices and a fixed finite non-modular lattice?

Comment: (I should have written "generated by distributive lattices and a fixed non-distributive modular lattice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variety is called *locally finite* if it has the property that its finitely generated algebras are finite. This is equivalent to the property that its finitely generated free algebras are finite. So, the questions may be rewritten as:

(1) Is there a locally finite variety of lattices larger than the variety of distributive lattices? 
(2) Is there a largest locally finite variety of lattices?

Every variety generated by a single finite algebra is locally finite, so there are lots of locally finite varieties of lattices. Any variety generated by a finite, nondistributive lattice will properly contain the variety of distributive lattices, hence will be an answer to Question (1).
[There do exist locally finite varieties of lattices that are not generated by a single finite lattice, like the variety generated by all lattices of height 2.]

If there were a largest locally finite variety of lattices, then by the answer to Question (1) it would have to contain every finite lattice. But the variety generated by all finite lattices is the variety of all lattices, and the variety of all lattices is not locally finite. Hence the answer to Question (2) is No.

**A comment on the comments:**
The class of semidistributive lattices forms a quasivariety, and therefore
has free objects over any set. But this quasivariety is not locally finite. The free semidistributive lattice on 3 generators is infinite.